# Assertion in the Test Class for ApexRest

Tags: apex, code-coverage, apexrest, failing-tests

I have a Apex Class which is exposed as a Rest API, the method is current void like below

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/SFDataAPI/*')
global with sharing class SFDataAPI {    
    @HttpGet
    global static void doGet() {
        String result = '';
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        String segmentID = req.params.get('SegmentID');
        List<Account> accs = [SELECT Name,Parent.Name FROM Account WHERE  Data_Source_ID__c =  :segmentID ];
        Account acc = accs[0];
            Map<String,String> resultMap = new Map<String,String> {
                'Site Account Name' => acc.Name,
                    'Parent Account Name'=> acc.Parent.Name
                    };
        result = JSON.serialize( resultMap);
        RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(result);
        }   
}
```

I tried writing my Test class like below

```
@IsTest
public class SFDataAPITest {
    @IsTest static void testUnit1()
    {
        Test.startTest();
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
        req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/SFDataAPI'; 
        req.params.put('SegmentID', 'TestPAX123');
        req.httpMethod = 'GET';
        req.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response = res;
         SFDataAPI.doGet();
        //System.debug();
        Test.stopTest();          
    }
 }
```

I not able to do the assertion here because when I try assign the response from the API in to the String or list throws error saying `Illegal assignment from void to Account` or `Illegal assignment from void to String` how can I handle that here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using return value, you can directly use the `RestContext` response.

As per the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restresponse.htm#apex_methods_system_restresponse) below is true for `responseBody` property of `RestResponse` class

The response is either the serialized form of the method return value or it's the value of the responseBody property based on the following rules:

- If the method returns void, then Apex REST returns the response in
  the responseBody property.
- If the method returns a value, then Apex
  REST serializes the return value as the response.

Below is the sample code to get the assert statements working

```
Test.startTest();
RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/SFDataAPI'; 
req.params.put('name', 'ABC');
req.httpMethod = 'GET';
req.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 

RestContext.request = req;
RestContext.response = res;

SFDataAPI.doGet();
res = RestContext.response; //Set the response here

String actual = res.responseBody.toString(); //Convert Blob to String
String expected = '{"Parent Account Name":null,"Site Account Name":"ABC"}'; //Your expected output
System.assertEquals(actual, expected);
System.assertEquals(200,res.statusCode); //Assert with expected status code. Status Code needs to be set in the main class.
Test.stopTest();
```

Also, you will have to create test `Acount` record with the matching `SegmentID`. So that the `doGet` method returns a record when the `SOQL` executes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I get `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getStatusCode() from the type System.RestResponse` and `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getBody() from the type System.RestResponse` error

Comment: Edited the Answer to add more details.